# I just started learning 'C'. I keep getting "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" when I try to run the following code on the terminal

Tags: c, printf, integer-arithmetic

I wrote this code to find out the average of any 3 numbers. Please help me out. I'd like to know where it went wrong. I wrote the same code in a new file and that was executed without any issues.

This is what I keep getting:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```c
#include <stdio.h>
//average of three numbers

int main() {
  int n1, n2, n3;
  printf("enter n1");
  scanf("%d", &n1);

  printf("enter n2");
  scanf("%d", &n2);

  printf("enter n3");
  scanf("%d", &n3);

  int average = n1/3+n2/3+n3/3;
  printf("average is : %d", average);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please copy&paste code that you actually compile and execute. Don't retype it. That only adds chances to introduce typos like `mian` in your code.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks, now I figured out what went wrong. I typed 'mian' in my original code

Comment: What comes before that error?

Comment: Ah, I missed that... In that case please always show the complete error message. There should be a description why `collect2.exe` failed. Something like undefined reference to `main`. The message you added in the title just means "something went wrong" with the <something> being explained in a line above or below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
int average = ( n1 + n2 + n3 ) / 3;
```

instead of

```
int average = n1/3+n2/3+n3/3;
```

Also you could write using a float result

```
double average = ( n1 + n2 + n3 ) / 3.0;
```

and then

```
printf("average is : %.2f\n", average);
```

Pay attention to that for readability it is better to add a space after the output of a call pf printf like

```
printf("enter n1 ");
               ^^^^
```

In general you should check whether a call of `scanf` was successful.

As for the run-time error then the reason can be of running the program that has a compiler or linker error.

Comment: @Boson I do not know what is the "initial file". I showed how the program should look.

Comment: I figured out where it went wrong. Thank you